# When $F(x,y)$ behaves like $xy$ for $x,y$ small

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $F(0,0)=0$.
and the partial derivatives of any order w.r.t. $x$ at $(0,0)$ are $0$,
and the partial derivatives of any order w.r.t. $y$ at $(0,0)$ are $0$ as well.
Can one get $|F(x,y)| < Cxy$ for $x,y$ small?

Comment: Yes, for example if F(x,y)=0 for every (x,y).

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
F(x,y)=\sin\left(\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)
$$
Approaching along $x=0$, $F(0,y)=0$, and approaching along $y=0$, $F(x,0)=0$. However, approaching along $x=y$,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}F(t,t)=\lim_{t\to0}\sin\left(\frac1{4t^2}\right)
$$
which doesn't exist, much less tend to $0$.

---

A continuous example that fails to meet the given criterion is
$$
F(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}
$$
This function is continuous, but
$$
\frac{F(x,y)}{xy}=\frac1{(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}
$$
is unbounded near $(0,0)$.

Comment: Why not use a simpler and more popular $F$, like $F(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @Giraffe: Certainly there are other examples. I thought the failure to come to a limit settled the issue quickly.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you so much! If F is analytic in a neighborhood of the origin, would the statement hold?

Comment: @user42081: Certainly. If $F$ were analytic, $F(0,0)=0$ and all derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are $0$ at $(0,0)$, then the only terms in the power series at $(0,0)$ left are multiples of $xy$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I just don't know how to resum that power series after factoring out the xy :(

Comment: @user42081: what do you mean "resume that power series"? Are you using the [Taylor series in two variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)?